# I can't seem to get customized auto-complete to work in python

Tags: python, autocomplete, command

I am having trouble understanding why I can get the customized auto-complete (using"TAB") to work.  I have found several example of code, all involving basically the same core code (some more complex, some less..).  Below is an example of the one of the simple code examples I have seen.

```
import readline
COMMANDS = ['extra', 'extension', 'stuff', 'errors',
            'email', 'foobar', 'foo']

def complete(text, state):
    for cmd in COMMANDS:
        if cmd.startswith(text):
            if not state:
                return cmd
            else:
                state -= 1

readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
readline.set_completer(complete)
raw_input('Enter section name: ')
```

When I try to execute the code, I just get the standard auto-complete (of python commands/functions).

For example: In the above example when I do:

```
"Enter a section: " ext<TAB>
```

I get 'extract' (a python command) instead of 'extension' (one of the python commands in the list above.

Comment: The code works as expected. See http://asciinema.org/a/6544

Comment: works for me as well.

Comment: `extract` is not a Python command...

Comment: falsetru and cmd, you are correct.  I have a couple questions though.  When I run the script from windows command line, it works correctly.  However, If I am editing the script in IDLE and run it (using IDLE), it doesn't work.  Why is this?  My next question is for falsetru (who provided working proof of the code).  When you typed the leter 'e', how did you get it to print out the list of all the commands starting with 'e'?